# Are params of a form available to helpers in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I was following Michael Hartl's tutorial to build a sign up form with login. I thought I would try and add a remember me check box to the login form and make it's value default at 0 and then 1 when checked.

I added an if statement in my sessionshelper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def login(user)
    if params[:remember_me]
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.password_salt]
    current_user = user
   else
    cookies[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.password_salt]
    current_user = user
   end
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def logout
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    current_user = nil
  end

  private

  def user_from_remember_token
    User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
  end

  def remember_token
    cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
  end

end
```

....but for some reason when ever I log in with boxed checked or not checked the cookie expiry time and date is never set. It always says "At end of session" when I check cookie info in firefox. Am I missing something?

my controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end


  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email password combination"
      render 'new'
    else
      login user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>      
  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>     
  Remember me? <%= f.check_box :remember_me, :value => 1 %>
  <%= f.submit "Log in", :id => "login_submit" %>
  <% end %>
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your form template to the question?

Comment: Note that the `:value => 1` is not necessary, see [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my issue

```
 def login(user)
    if params[:session][:remember_me] == "1"
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.password_salt]
    current_user = user
   elsif params[:session][:remember_me] == "0"
    cookies.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.password_salt]
    current_user = user
   end
  end
```

view:

```
    <%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>      
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>     
      Remember me? <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.submit "Log in", :id => "login_submit" %>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `params[:session][:remember_me]` instead of `params[:remember_me]`. Compare to it to your controller's user authentication line.

Comment: That works as it sets the cookie to expiry in 2031 but when I don't check the box it does the same thing.

Comment: See my other comment above, maybe the `:value => 1` is throwing it off, remove it and try again.

Comment: And although I'm not sure, I think you also need to check explicitly for the parameter being `"1"`, not just check if it's there; `if params[:session][:remember_me] == "1"`,

Comment: The value I was setting was throwing it off. Thanks rdvdijk.